# Can't Understand Ruby On Rails Nested Model Form with JavaScript Tutorial

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I watched a tutorial for Nested Model Forms: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amT27SfNhKM&ab_channel=RailscastsReloaded

I can't figure out what is going on there, to be honest, and I also ran into a few problems. For example:

I tried implementing the code, and wrote the javascript described in the tutorial:

```
$('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
        alert("----")
        time = new Date().getTime()
        regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
        $(this).before( $(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time) )
        event.preventDefault()
```

If I understand correctly, this is inserting new form elements into the web page and replacing their id's with generated ones, so that webserver will be able to identify them. However, what happens, is that RegEx replaces '**id**' in 'h**id**den', making my `<%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>` form visible.

Also, I have no idea what is going on here (I made some adjustments, as I am not using associations, but instead a JSON based field in my model):

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = Education.new({name: '', degree: ''})
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
        render("education_fields", f:builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: :id, fields: fields.gsub("\n","") })
end
```

Is this tutorial even any good at all? The way he addresses the problem seems extremely convoluted.